# Insert into ... Select *, how to ignore identity?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table with the exact structure of a concrete table `T`. It was created like this:

```
select top 0 * into #tmp from T
```

After processing and filling in content into `#tmp`, I want to copy the content back to `T` like this:

```
insert into T select * from #tmp
```

This is okay as long as `T` doesn't have identity column, but in my case it does. Is there any way I can ignore the auto-increment identity column from `#tmp` when I copy to `T`? My motivation is to avoid having to spell out every column name in the Insert Into list.

EDIT: toggling identity_insert wouldn't work because the pkeys in `#tmp` may collide with those in `T` if rows were inserted into `T` outside of my script, that's if `#tmp` has auto-incremented the pkey to sync with T's in the first place.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about why you want a temp table copy in the first place please? There may be a better way to accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: 1. it gives me a chance to preview the data before I do the insert
2. I have joins between temp tables as part of my calculation; temp tables allows me to focus on the exact set data that I am working with.
I think that was it. Any suggestions/comments?

Comment: Is your purpose simply to double the data that's already in there? Or are you clearing out T before you do the insert into?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As identity will be generated during insert anyway, could you simply remove this column from #tmp before inserting the data back to T?

```
alter table #tmp drop column id
```

**UPD:** Here's an example I've tested in SQL Server 2008:

```
create table T(ID int identity(1,1) not null, Value nvarchar(50))
insert into T (Value) values (N'Hello T!')
select top 0 * into #tmp from T
alter table #tmp drop column ID
insert into #tmp (Value) values (N'Hello #tmp')
insert into T select * from #tmp
drop table #tmp
select * from T
drop table T
```

Comment: From my simple experiments, it looks like this does the job :) thanks. Can anybody think of any ways where the cell contents maybe misaligned due to the fact that the source table #tmp has 1 less column than the destination T?

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but inserting back into the original table doesn't work, it says "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.".  i.e. this command "insert into T select * from #tmp" doesn't work.

Comment: @kristianp I've added a full working test code to the answer, but it's possible that you are trying to solve a slightly different problem, e.g. you might have identity insert already on. If other answers to this question and searching SO won't help you, it might make sense to create a new question with more details about your situation.

Answer (score 13):

SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON

INSERT command

SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF

Comment: There may be primary key collision if I do that because by the time #tmp is ready for copying, same keys may have been inserted into T.

Comment: Ahh, that would work. I didn't start the transaction until #tmp's were ready for copying ( I have many tmps to calculate ) to minimize lock time. I guess now it's justifiable.

Comment: I got this error(with an identity column):An explicit value for the identity column in table 'myTable' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Answer (score 9):

See answers [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/936/116268) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/925/116268):

```
select * into without_id from with_id
union all
select * from with_id where 1 = 0
```

Reason:

> When an existing identity column is selected into a new table, the new column inherits the IDENTITY property, unless one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The SELECT statement contains a join, GROUP BY clause, or aggregate function.
> - Multiple SELECT statements are joined by using UNION.
> - The identity column is listed more than one time in the select list.
> - The identity column is part of an expression.
> - The identity column is from a remote data source.
>
> If any one of these conditions is true, the column is created NOT NULL instead of inheriting the IDENTITY property. If an identity column is required in the new table but such a column is not available, or you want a seed or increment value that is different than the source identity column, define the column in the select list using the IDENTITY function. See "Creating an identity column using the IDENTITY function" in the Examples section below.

All credit goes to [Eric Humphrey](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/247/eric-humphrey-lotsahelp) and [bernd_k](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/136/bernd-k)

Comment: This is brilliant.  Exactly what the original poster asked for.

Answer (score 1):

```
set identity_insert on
```

Use this.

Answer (score 1):

Not with `SELECT *` - if you selected every column but the identity, it will be fine.  The only way I can see is that you could do this by dynamically building the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Just list the colums you want to re-insert, you should never use select * anyway. If you don't want to type them ,just drag them from the object browser (If you expand the table and drag the word, columns, you will get all of them, just delete the id column)

Comment: design error or something, this table has some 80 columns, 30 of which are deprecated. Because of the way #tmp is created, I think it's okay to make an exception of using select *.

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO #Table
SELECT MAX(Id) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id)

Answer (score 0):

Might an "update where T.ID = #tmp.ID" work?

Answer (score -1):

> 1. it gives me a chance to preview the data before I do the insert
> 2. I have joins between temp tables as part of my calculation; temp tables allows me to focus on the exact set data that I am working with. I think that was it. Any suggestions/comments?

For part 1, as mentioned by Kolten in one of the comments, encapsulating your statements in a transaction and adding a parameter to toggle between display and commit will meet your needs. For Part 2, I would needs to see what "calculations" you are attempting. Limiting your data to a temp table may be over complicating the situation.